# Java. Ignore/disable key function but still capture the keyEvent

Tags: java, keyevent

I have a JTextField and I want to record keyEvent when I focus on it.
This is not hard and I can already print out all key names (such as "F1", "ESCAPE", "A", "M") except "TAB".

The problem is, the focus would change when I press "TAB" and a character is deleted when I press "BACKSPACE". I want to avoid this but keep the keyEvent. So I wonder if it's possible to ignore the key function when I press it. Any ideas?

Comment: Try implementing a document filter to filter any actions whenever you are typing in the text field. Refer to below links to get more info : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To eliminate the Tab-Away feature from a **JTextField** you will need to set its **setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled** property to ***false***. Once this is done focus can not be lost from the JTextField by hitting the TAB (or SHIFT-TAB) key and the fact that the TAB key was pressed **can** be detected within the JTextField's **KeyPressed** event.

The easiest way to remove the the Backspace/Delete feature from a JTextField is with a custom [DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html). By overriding the filter's **remove()** method with a empty method effectively eliminates Backspace or Delete key capabilities.

This can all be accomplished with the use of a single method which I have provided below. The method allows you to disable or enable Tab and Backspace capabilities from the supplied JTextField:

```
/**
 * Disables (and can again Enable) the TAB (or SHIFT-TAB), BACKSPACE, and DELETE keys when 
 * used within the supplied JTextField.<br><br>
 * 
 * When the Tab key or Backspace key is hit then it can be detected within the 
 * JTextField's KeyPressed Event by way of:<pre>
 * 
 *      if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
 *          System.out.println("TAB Key Pressed!");
 *      } 
 *      else if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
 *          System.out.println("BACKSPACE Key Pressed!");
 *      }</pre>
 * 
 * @param jtextfield (JTextField) The desired JTextField variable name to 
 * control.<br>
 * 
 * @param ON_OFF (Optional - Boolean - Default is true) If true (default) then 
 * Tab and Backspace is not allowed within the supplied JTextField. If false is 
 * supplied then Tab and Backspace is allowed within the supplied JTextField.
 */
public void noTABorBACKSPACE(JTextField jtextfield, boolean... ON_OFF) {
    boolean on = true;  // Default ON - No Tab Away and No Backspace allowed.
    if (ON_OFF.length > 0) {
        on = ON_OFF[0];
    }
    if (on) {
        // Remove the TAB Away feature from the JTextField.
        jtextfield.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(!on);

        // Disable the Backspace feature from the JTextField.
        // This is done with a custom Document Filter.
        ((AbstractDocument) jtextfield.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(
            new DocumentFilter(){
                @Override
                // By overriding the remove() method with an empty remove() 
                // method we effectively eliminate Backspace capabilities.
                public void remove(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int i, int i1) 
                    throws BadLocationException {  }
            }
        );
    }
    else {
        // Re-enable the TAB Away feature for the JTextField.
        jtextfield.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(!on);

        // Re-enable the Backspace feature for the JTextField.
        // This is done by removing our custom Document Filter.
        ((AbstractDocument) jtextfield.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(null);
    }
}
```

**How to use this method:**

```
// To disable TAB and BACKSPACE
noTABorBACKSPACE(jTextField1);
//         OR
// noTABorBACKSPACE(jTextField1, true);   

// To re-enable TAB and BACKSPACE
noTABorBACKSPACE(jTextField1, false);
```

While the TAB and BACKSPACE features are disabled within the supplied JTextField you can determine if those specific keys were pressed by way of the JTextField's **KeyPressed** event, for example:

```
private void jTextField1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
        System.out.println("TAB Key Hit!");
    }
    else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
        System.out.println("BACKSPACE Key Hit!");
    }
}
```

You will notice that when the JTextField's **setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled** property is set to boolean **true** you will not be able to detect when the TAB key is hit and this is because the TAB key is always consumed by the [KeyboardFocusManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html). This is not so when the **setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled** property is set to boolean **false**.

So far the code provided gives means to remove Tab-Away and Backspace/Delete capabilities but perhaps you want to keep the **Delete** key active and just remove capabilities for the TAB and BACKSPACE key. If this is the case then you can do this from within the JTextField's **KeyPressed** event by consuming the BACKSPACE key press:

```
private void jTextField1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
        System.out.println("TAB Key Hit!");
    }
    else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
        System.out.println("BACKSPACE Key Hit!");
        evt.consume(); // Consume the BACKSPACE Key Press.
    }
}
```

To stop the TAB key from moving focus you will still need to set the **setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled** property to **false**.